# Pre-Allocated List

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

I have two lists of objects

```
list<QC> qcB;
list<QC> qcS;
```

and am using emplace_back() to insert items into them. Since I realized that inserting the items was taking too long, I started searching about allocators, which I have never used, to see if I was able to make things run faster. I read somewhere that I would be able to get the default allocator for the list, and allocate space on it ahead of time, so I tried allocating space in one of the lists:

```
qcB.get_allocator().allocate(100000);
```

I am unsure if this was supposed to work or not, but the truth is that the emplace_back() is taking the same amount of time with both the lists, even though one of them is allocating space beforehand.

Is this supposed to work? Should this be done in a different way, instead of trying to allocate space in the default allocator? I am clearing the lists from time to time, may this be affecting the allocated space?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The list calls `allocate()` when it wants some memory. Calling it yourself won't "allocate space in the list", it will just give you some memory from the allocator, which the list then can't use. If the default allocator is too slow (and you've determined through measurement that that's the bottleneck), then writing your own allocator might (or might not) help. Doing weird things with the standard allocator won't help.

Comment: @MikeSeymour can you point me to some documentation for that? I have never used allocators and have no idea on how to implement a simple thing just for pre-allocating some items to perform a test. I do not know if I can inherit from the default std allocator and just make it allocate n items in advance...

Comment: My googling skills are probably no better than yours, but this might be useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator.

Comment: what is the size of a `QC` element? How much is the object itself and how much is owned by the object?

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks for that, but actually I had already seen that page :) even though my googling skills are not so bad, the issue is that I don't quite understand what I should do with that. At the bottom of that link there is an example, but what do I do with that? Do I have to change anything in its implementation? Or do I only have to say that a SimpleAllocator instance will be my list's allocator, and before setting it as the allocator, calling allocate() on that instance with the number of items to reserve?

Comment: @MariusSiuram I have no idea what that means...

Comment: I was, more or less, asking for a `sizeof` ("size of the element itself") and some information about if it has "extras" (like a big `std::string` inside generated on initialization).

Comment: @BlunT: You'll have to implement all the Allocator requirements (the `SimpleAllocator` doesn't, so isn't a very useful example). Then use `list<QC, MyAllocator>` instead of `list<QC>`. If your `allocate` and `deallocate` are faster than `::operator new` and `::operator delete`, then you might see an improvement. For example, you could use a simple linked-list of preallocated memory blocks large enough for a list node, so that they usually just remove and replace blocks on that list.

Comment: @MariusSiuram there is nothing expensive in the object initialization, and it is not the bottleneck. the members are 3 ints, a double, and another object which has also 3 ints and a double.

Comment: @MikeSeymour well that is exactly my point. I have no idea how to implement all that stuff. I think I will follow your suggestion on MariusSiuram answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the Standard Library `list`, it is typically a linked list algorithm or similar.

Assuming that you have done a good profiling and the insertion is indeed the problem, and assuming that you only want to do `emplace_back` calls. Then use a `vector`, which allows you to call `reserve` and should have a little more performance.

```
vector<QC> qcB;
qcB.reserve(10000);
```

But I fear that your actual bottleneck is the object `QC` initialization, and this cannot be `reserve`d. In this scenario, you could preinitialize the objects (in case it makes sense to initialize the object and then put actual data in it).

Like this (quick&dirty draft):

```
vector<QC> qcB;
qcB.resize(10000);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    qcB[i].populate_object();
}
```

Comment: This is not an option. I would use a circular vector if it was an option, but in this case, since I have erases in different places of the list, vector is not an option. I have profiled, and I do know that this is a bottleneck.

Comment: "vector is not an option" - have you checked and profiled that? If you don't need to preserve the order, then you can quickly erase any element by swapping with `back()`, followed by `pop_back()`. If you do need to, then it might still be surprisingly fast due to cache locality.

Comment: If you do not believe, check out this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo, then profile.

Comment: @MikeSeymour well actually when I mentioned it was not an option, I was considering the default vector, or the circular vector I usually use, both of them not fans of removing items in the middle. I will look into that swapping and popping the last element, as it will probably have a huge performance boost over the current list performance.